# Unbinding jQuery Click Event doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Have a look at
http://jsfiddle.net/60j9hhz7/3/

UPDATED FIDDLE (use this)
http://jsfiddle.net/60j9hhz7/10/

html:

```
<div class="mycontainer">
  <a href="#" class="test">test</a>   
</div><br/>
<a href="#" class="unbind">doesn't work</a><br />
<a href="#" class="unbind2">works</a><br />
<a href="#" class="unbind3">works too</a>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {
  alert('hello');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click', '.mycontainer a');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind2', function (e) {
   $(document).off('click');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind3', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click', '.test');
});
```

In the fiddle you'll see that the first *off* doesn't work (the alert still pops up) while all the others work.

Could somebody explain why this is and if there is a solution?
I need to be able to target all links within a certain container but they may have hooked up their click events with different selectors.

Problem is *unbind2* is too unspecific and *unbind3* too specific

Comment: you are clearing click on a tag

Comment: yes, but why shouldn't this work?
If I bind an event via *on* like that
`$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
})`

it does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem you need  `.off()` to use the same selector as the bonded `.on()` event

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {//see .test
  alert('hello');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click', 'a');//will not work
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind2', function (e) {
   $(document).off('click');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind3', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click', '.test');//will work
});
```

exp2:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mycontainer a', function (e) {
  alert('hello');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click', '.mycontainer a');//will work 
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind2', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unbind3', function (e) {
  $(document).off('click', '.test');//will not work
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/60j9hhz7/11/

Comment: ok, so it's by design.
Just to be clear: If I want to unbind an event I have to unbind on the jquery Object I bound it with the same selector? 
$(document) works while $('.test') doesnt.

And this is the only way?
Isn't there an easy way to just unbind every click event from a certain element?

Like 
`$('.test').off('click');`

Beware: the code doesn't work, it's just an example

Comment: @Arikael No, there is no 'simple' way because this would bring many performance issues to handle it (processing element selector and comparing it to any ancestors handler matched selector) and could have many side effects. The easiest way could be just to use: `$('.test').replaceWith(function () {
    return $(this).clone().on('click', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });`  http://jsfiddle.net/60j9hhz7/12/  This would unbind any event bound to element itself and avoid event to bubble through DOM, so not firing any delegated event

Comment: @Arikael This is more relevant example where this would have been an use case: http://jsfiddle.net/60j9hhz7/13/

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly (wait, could be quite ambiguous indeed...) explained in [off() doc](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

***.off( events [, selector ] [, handler ] )***

**selector**
Type: *String*

> A selector which should match the one originally passed to .on() when
>   attaching event handlers

Comment: And `.unbind2` does work because you're turning off *all* click events, regardless of selector

Comment: thanks for your answer, I chose madalin's answer as solution because he was a tad faster

Comment: @Arikael No problem, he gave relevant examples btw :)